# 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

This is my code. Do you know what is this error? Thank you!

```
struct PlaceholderImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageModel: PlaceholderImageViewModel
    @Environment(\.MyImageCacheValue) var cache: MyImageCache
    
    init(urlString: String) {
        imageModel = PlaceholderImageViewModel(urlString: urlString, cache: cache) // error: 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialize `PlaceholderImageViewModel` before `MyImageCache` is initialized. One way to resolve this is to create `PlaceholderImageViewModel` in the caller view of `PlaceholderImageView` and just pass the model directly.

```
struct PlaceholderImageViewSuperView: View {

    @Environment(\.MyImageCacheValue) var cache: MyImageCache

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("Go to image view", destination: PlaceholderImageView(imageModel: PlaceholderImageViewModel(urlString: urlString, cache: cache)))
    }
}

struct PlaceholderImageView: View {

    @ObservedObject var imageModel: PlaceholderImageViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Any text here")
    }
}
```